# ImportError: cannot import name DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I am using Pandas for the first time and trying to import Pandas, `DataFrame` and `pandas.io.data` as such

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas import DataFrame
import pandas.io.data
```

I get the error

> "ImportError: cannot import name DataFrame"

and

> "ImportError: No module named io.data"

I have tried the following to find the source of error on Ubuntu 14.04:

```
$pip show pandas
-> Version: 0.14.0
Location: /home/new-pc/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages
$$PATH
-> bash: /home/new-pc/anaconda/bin
```

Not sure where else to look for errors. Thanks for all the inputs.

Comment: Are you sure you're python script is being executed by anaconda's python and not the default python?

Comment: What's the output of `which python`?

Comment: I actually found the error. I called the file pandas.py. I simply changed the name.

Answer (score 1):

You must be mixing Python installations, with several `python` programs/distributions (Anaconda), and maybe python version (2 and 3)

The following commands should not produce any error:

```
sudo apt-get install python
sudo pip install pandas
python -c'import pandas as pd; from pandas import DataFrame; import pandas.io.data'
```

Comment: do you know what the command is for windows ?

Answer (score 1):

It will happen if you call your file `pandas.py` and try to run it. You should rename the file then.

It will also occur if you save a `pandas.py` file in the Python directory. Check if you have any files called `pandas.py` there and rename/move those files to another location.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
from pandas_datareader import data
```

as shown in the example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51886766/import-pandas-io-data-as-web-gives-me-a-error-saying-no-module-name-for-panda)

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have saved any file with same names as in pandas libraries, such as saving file name as DataFrame.py. Always avoid naming the program as same as library name check all the location.Once you remove/rename your python script will run without any issue.