# "import pandas.io.data as web " gives me a error saying no module name for pandas.io.data

Tags: python, pandas

Im just learning python and trying to use it for stock anlyses.
using stockstats.

1. I installed stockstats by
   pip install stockstats
2. imported pandas
   import pandas
3. tried to import data
   import pandas.io.data
   got a error saying module pandas.io.data does not exist

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I got this error out of the box with Anaconda 4.4:

```
>>> import pandas.io.data
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/io/data.py", line 2, in <module>
    "The pandas.io.data module is moved to a separate package "
ImportError: The pandas.io.data module is moved to a separate package (pandas-datareader). After installing the pandas-datareader package (https://github.com/pydata/pandas-datareader), you can change the import ``from pandas.io import data, wb`` to ``from pandas_datareader import data, wb``.
```

The error message is pretty nice. It recommends you go install `pandas-datareader` from `https://github.com/pydata/pandas-datareader`. Then change your import to `from pandas_datareader import data`.

Or you can just `pip install pandas-datareader`.

After that, `from pandas_datareader import data` works as expected:

```
Matthews-MacBook-Pro:python matt$ python
Python 3.6.4 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, Jan 16 2018, 12:04:33) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Clang 4.0.1 (tags/RELEASE_401/final)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from pandas_datareader import data
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

> The sub-package pandas.io.data was deprecated in v.0.17 and removed in
> v.0.19. Instead there has been created a separately installable
> pandas-datareader package. This will allow the data modules to be
> independently updated on your pandas installation.

### Installing

To install required packages through pip :

```
pip install pandas-datareader
OR
pip install git+https://github.com/pydata/pandas-datareader.git
```

### Testing

```
from pandas_datareader import data
df=data.DataReader('AAPL','yahoo','2016/1/1','2017/1/1')
df.head()
```

[image: yaahhoo]

### Resources

- [pandas-datareader](https://pandas-datareader.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)
- [Remote Data Access](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.22/remote_data.html)